# How to return a response from xmlhttprequest javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I don't know why this function is returning undefined. Please help me... **Run Snippet**

```js
function xhr(url) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
            return (this.response);
        }
    });
    
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();

}

let arr =  xhr('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very very simple, Maybe you're new to Javascript, If you are not aware Js is an `asynchronous` language, it means that it would not block or wait for any function to complete which might be time consuming ( in this case a request to the server), This helps it to process other things meanwhile the request is taking place.

So in your case, it's creating the request to the server, but at the same time continues to execute your function and return the default value, i.e `undefined`, You can pass a `callback` to be called when the request is completed.

```js
function callWhenFinished(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
}


function xhr(url) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.responseType = 'json';

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      callWhenFinished(this.response); // callback
    }
  });

  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.send();

}


xhr('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
```

Answer (score 0):

you trying to make async request, but expect that it will work in synchronous way.

The way you solve your problem is:

- use callbacks
- use promises
- use async/await (that's just wrapper of of promises)

i recommend you to use promises instead of XMLHttpRequest. it's easy to understand and it's modern way to work with requests.

related links here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp